# AngularJs ng-options get id

Tags: angularjs

This should be really simple but I don't know how to do it.
I have a select control which looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : saveForm.status.$invalid && !saveForm.status.$pristine }">
    <label class="control-label">Status</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="status" ng-options="status.name for status in controller.statuses.data track by status.id" ng-model="controller.model.data.statusId" required>
        <option value="">Select a status</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

the **ng-model** was bound to **controller.model.data.status** because at the time I wanted the entire object. Now I only require the selected **id**, so I changed the **ng-model** to **controller.model.data.statusId** and as you would expect the whole **status** object is now binding to that model location.
How can I get it to just select the **id** instead of the whole object while showing the names in the select control?

codepen example as requested:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/yNgLqp

Comment: Could you make a codepen please ?

Comment: model: {{ controller.model.statusId.id }}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I prefer the `select as` syntax from [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions/#usage).  (This does not work with `track by`).  Specifically, I like the form
`select as label for value in array`, which lets you change what is actually binding (`select`) from what is displayed (`label`).

From the documentation, the syntax has 4 parts:

- `select` this is the expression you actually want to bind to.  Often it's a property of an element in the array.  In your case it's `status.id`
- `label` this is the expression that determines how to display the object in the dropdown.  Again, this is often a property, but it can really be any angular expression (like `status.name + ': ' + status.description`) In yours it's just `status.name`
- `value` is the name (alias) you want to use for a single element of the array.  In yours it's `status` but it's just a name so you could change it to just about anything (you would have to change the `select` and `label` too).
- `array` is obviously the array you want to use as the dropdown data source.  In yours it's `controller.statuses`.

In your code fully assembled:

```
ng-options="status.id as status.name for status in controller.statuses"
```

Comment: works perfectly. I still don't understand the syntax, but I will some day :)

Comment: @r3plica I added a bit more explanation.  Hope it helps.

Comment: @ryanuyu that is brilliant, I understand that now :)

Comment: Better explanation then the documentation. Cheers!