# Trying to display value in my select option

Tags: angularjs, select

When I try to display my value the select box is always empty. The value is a integer 0 1 2 3 . In this case it should show 0, but the box is empty. What am I doing wrong?
vmDialog.dataModel.requestType value is equal to a 0 integer, but not displaying.

```
<select class="form-control " name="requestType" ng-model="vmDialog.dataModel.requestType">
                  <option value=0>0</option>
                  <option value="{{0}}">0</option>
                  <option value="0">0</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: please show your logic for where the options data is supposed to come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there is a simple HTML issue, you need to ensure that each option has a unique value, so far you have used the value 0 for all the options, so when the `requestType` has a value of `0`, the UI cannot pick which of the items should be selected.

If the value supposed to be one of `0,1,2,3` then you need to make sure that there is an option with a corresponding `value` that can be selected.

- What you probably want to do is bind the options to an array that is in the view model:

  ```
  // on vmDialog
  var requestTypeOptions = [
    { name = 'Zero', value = 0 },
    { name = 'One', value = 1 },
    { name = 'Two', value = 2 },
    { name = 'Three', value = 3 },
  ];
  ```

  Then in the view: (using [`ng-options`](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-options.asp))

  ```
  <select class="form-control"
          name="requestType" 
          ng-model="vmDialog.dataModel.requestType" 
          ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in vmDialog.requestTypeOptions track by o.value | orderby: 'value'" 
          class="form-control input-sm">
  </select>
  ```

  A good write-up for ng-options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30507651/1690217

  You could also use ng-repeat if you need to customise the template:

  ```
  <select class="form-control " name="requestType" ng-model="vmDialog.dataModel.requestType">
      <md-option ng-value="o.value" ng-repeat="oin vmDialog.requestTypeOptions | orderBy: 'value'">{{o.name}}</md-option>
  </select>
  ```